# Error messages after creating a new linux user

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

I have created a new debian user using a Perl script with the CPAN module [`Unix::Passwd::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unix%3a%3aPasswd%3a%3aFile) (I have used this module because i've been asked to create the user without using `adduser` or `useradd`).

This module creates the user by adding the lines in:

- `/etc/passwd`
- `/etc/shadow`
- `/etc/group`
- `/etc/gshadow`

Then the Perl script creates the home directory using:

```
mkdir $directory;
chown $user, $directory;
```

After this I tried to log in and got the following error messages:

```
Could not update ICEauthority file /home/user/.ICEauthority

There is a problem with the configuration server.(/usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256)

Nautilus could not create the following required folders: /home/user/Desktop, /home/user/.nautilus
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really have the comma in `chown user, /home/user` or is that a typo in the question?

Comment: Is not a typo, I want 'user' to be the owner of /home/user, am i doing it wrong? sorry, i am new to perl programming.

Comment: Then you should be using `chown user /home/user`

Comment: I am using chown in a perl script: chown $user, $directory, where user is the username and directory the path to /home/$user. If I dont use the comma i get an error: "Missing comma after first argument to chown function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chown` is failing because you aren't giving it the correct arguments. The return value is the number of files modified so you can use that to check for success:

```
chown "user", "file" or die "Couldn't chown";
```

The correct arguments for [`chown`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chown.html) are:

```
chown $uid, $gid, @filenames;
```

e.g.

```
chown 123, 456, "/home/user";
chown 123, -1, "/home/user"; # Don't change the group id
```

The user and group ids of the newly created user can be extracted from the result of [`Unix::Passwd::File::add_user`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unix%3a%3aPasswd%3a%3aFile#add_user-args---status-msg-result-meta):

```
my $result = add_user( ... );
if ($result->[0] == 200) { # Success
    my $uid = $result->[2]->{'uid'};
    my $gid = $result->[2]->{'gid'};
    ...
}
```

Comment: This answer solved the problem, now chmod is working properly and I am not getting error messages. I guess the system could not properly setup the home directory because it was owned by root. Thank you all for your help!